# How to alias a particular cmake command

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to work around a QtCreator bug (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-20972) where QtCreator fails to open a CMake project because it is trying to create a socket file in /tmp/RANDOM_PATH/socket whereas "RANDOM_PATH" does not exist.

I can reproduce the issue manually with:

> $ /usr/bin/cmake -E server --pipe=/tmp/not-existing-path/socket
>   --experimental CMake Error: Internal Error with /tmp/not-existing-path/socket: EACCES

The suggestion given in https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-18444 is to create an alias of cmake which would report

> "serverMode":false

when given the command

> cmake -E capabilities

which on my machine (Ubuntu 18.04) outputs:

> {"generators":[{"extraGenerators":[],"name":"Watcom WMake","platformSupport":false,"toolsetSupport":false},{"extraGenerators":["CodeBlocks","CodeLite","Sublime Text 2","Kate","Eclipse CDT4","KDevelop3"],"name":"Unix Makefiles","platformSupport":false,"toolsetSupport":false},{"extraGenerators":["CodeBlocks","CodeLite","Sublime Text 2","Kate","Eclipse CDT4"],"name":"Ninja","platformSupport":false,"toolsetSupport":false}],"serverMode":true,"version":{"isDirty":false,"major":3,"minor":10,"patch":2,"string":"3.10.2","suffix":""}}

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

I've tried to add such an alias:

> cmake='cmake | sed "s/\"serverMode\":true/\"serverMode\":false/g"'

, but the issue is that the "sed" command needs to be after the arguments given to cmake, and not before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see from that bug report:

> If you want to run a newer cmake without server-mode, then you will need to write a wrapper around cmake that removes the server-mode support indicator from the output reported by
>
> > ```
> > cmake -E capabilities
> > ```

That would be something like

```
cmake() {
    if [[ "$*" == "-E capabilities" ]]; then
        command cmake "$@" | jq -c 'del(.serverMode)'
    else
        command cmake "$@"
    fi
}
```

You make have to make that a standalone script rather than a shell function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know jq.